# How to not execute JS code on specific page

Tags: javascript

I have this code to prevent executing on page ucp.php?mode=register, but i want it to work on other pages. With this code its not working (not executing on all webpages).:

```
<script>
if ( window.location.toString().match(/[/ucp.php\?mode=register]/)){ 
    var fileref=document.createElement('script')
    fileref.setAttribute("type","text/javascript")
    fileref.setAttribute("src","//sk.search.etargetnet.com/generic/uni.php?g=5:500")
    fileref.setAttribute("async","true")
    fileref.setAttribute("data-ad-type","iframe v2.0")
    fileref.setAttribute("charset","utf-8")

 }
</script>
```

How to prevent exectugin this JS:

```
    <script type="text/javascript" async="true" data-ad-type="iframe v2.0" charset="utf-8" src="//sk.search.etargetnet.com/generic/uni.php?g=5:500"></script>
```

on page ucp.php?mode=register

Thats the question.

Comment: `window.location.toString().match(/[/ucp.php\?mode=register]/)` is matching the current page URL and looking for a pattern of `[/ucp.php\?mode=register]`. You'll need to alter this pattern, or simply remove this condition, and only place this code on pages where you want it to be executed. If you'd like to alter the pattern, do some research on RegEx.

Comment: I have robust webpage so I dont wanna put the code on each folder. Just on the page ucp.php?mode=register I want to not execute the script above.

Comment: Why not just use normal operations on `window.location` instead of regex? `window.location.pathname` will give you the page, `window.location.search` will give you the query string.

Comment: How to do it with window.location.pathname? Could you please send answer?

Comment: @MarcelinoPietero is that any reason why you dont what to do this in php?

Comment: I use it in .html file (because of phpBB).

Answer (score 3):

On the first line of your script you check which url it matches `if ( window.location.toString().match(/[/ucp.php\?mode=register]/)){`

you need to change this to include all URLs you want the script to work on. Since we don't know which pages you want it to know on, we can't tell you exactly what to put there.

If you want it to work on all pages, just remove the `if ...` and the `}` that closes the if

Comment: I have robust webpage so I dont wanna put the code on each folder. Just on the page ucp.php?mode=register I want to not execute the script above.

Answer (score 1):

If you want it to execute on all page except the one you are searching for, you need to first negate the match, since you are searching for that specific page and you want the OPPOSITE of that.

Second, your regex is broken. You need to escape the several characters, since they act as control characters and mean very specific things to the regex parser.

```
<script>
if ( !window.location.toString().match(/\/ucp\.php\?mode=register/g)){ 
    var fileref=document.createElement('script')
    fileref.setAttribute("type","text/javascript")
    fileref.setAttribute("src","//sk.search.etargetnet.com/generic/uni.php?g=5:500")
    fileref.setAttribute("async","true")
    fileref.setAttribute("data-ad-type","iframe v2.0")
    fileref.setAttribute("charset","utf-8")
    document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(fileref);
 }
</script>
```

Which is why people joke about solving a problem with regex now gives you two problems.

Comment: Now not executing the JS script on all pages. I want to not execute on the just specific page ucp.php?mode=register -> phpBB register form.

Comment: Then just remove the `!` in front of `window`

Comment: Still not works. This is the code i want to not execute on that page: <script type="text/javascript" async="true" data-ad-type="iframe v2.0" charset="utf-8" src="//sk.search.etargetnet.com/generic/uni.php?g=5:500"></script>

Comment: I mistook your escaped `?` for `\?` I edited my code. Try again.

Comment: @MarcelinoPietero It appears that nowhere in your code are you appending the new `script` element to the page. I updated my code.

Comment: Is there any particular reason the regex needs to be global?

Comment: @HashimAziz Not that I recall. It will simply match all occurrences.

Answer (score 0):

Try this, handle the logic in php rather than in JavaScript

```
<?php if(isset($_GET['mode']) && isset($_GET['mode']!="register")) {
<script>

    var fileref=document.createElement('script')
    fileref.setAttribute("type","text/javascript")
    fileref.setAttribute("src","//sk.search.etargetnet.com/generic/uni.php?g=5:500")
    fileref.setAttribute("async","true")
    fileref.setAttribute("data-ad-type","iframe v2.0")
    fileref.setAttribute("charset","utf-8")

 }
</script>
<?php } ?>
```

Comment: The question is for JavaScript.

Comment: I don’t think this is a bad answer. Just because the OP asked for a JS solution doesn’t make the OP right. It could be they’ve just got in too deep and didn’t think to look elsewhere. “My hammer won’t screw in this nail, but I want to use a hammer. Have you tried using a screwdriver?” As it’s a param it’s easy to get to in PHP.

Answer (score 0):

Try this instead of yours:

```
if (/\/ucp\.php\?mode=register$/i.test(window.location.href)==false){ 
     //your codes ....
 }
```

Also you can add script dynamically to your `document.head`:

```
if (/\/ucp\.php\?mode=register$/i.test(window.location.href)==false){ 
     var scr=document.createElement("script");
     scr.src="//sk.search.etargetnet.com/generic/uni.php?g=5:500";
     scr.type="text/javascript";
     document.head.appendChild(scr);
 }
```

Comment: Not working. Not executing script on all sites... I want to not execute just on specific :(